# JQuery Mobile stuck on loading spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, spinner, loading

I just added JQuery mobile to my project and now whenever I open the app on my phone it just stays stuck on a loading spinner even though it works on chrome on my computer.

I added it to the head of my project here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any help!

[image: Loading Spinner]

Comment: You have a java script error some where most likely.   Check console for errors.

Comment: The app opens fine without mobile and the console doesn't show any errors

Comment: there is no way this can be answered with out some more details

Comment: Definitely need to see more code